# VSCode Compile immediately stalls, displaying only "This is pdfTex" message

Tags: compiling, vscode

Trying to compile a MWE using VSCode (latex, latex workshop, and utilities all installed) using TeXlive. The compiler only shows the following and stalls, I've let it run for hours without progress:

```
**This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
```

Other useful info - this is on a Windows system (runs fine on a mac). The build recipe I'm using only calls `pdflatex`. Under the tools option I have:

```
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "command": "pdflatex",
            "args": [
                "--shell-escape",
                "-synctex=1",
                "-interaction=nonstopmode",
                "-file-line-error",
                "%DOC%"
            ],
            "env": {}
        },
```

and under recipes:

```
        {
            "name": "pdflatex",
            "tools": [
                "pdflatex"
            ]
        },
```

I've also tried the default `pdflatex, bibtex, pdflatex x2` to no success.

From powershell, it works fine:

```
pdflatex --shell-escape -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -file-line-error simple.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022) (preloaded format=pdflatex)
 \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./simple.tex
LaTeX2e <2022-06-01> patch level 5
L3 programming layer <2022-08-30>
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2021/10/04 v1.4n Standard LaTeX document class
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-pdftex.def)
(./simple.aux) [1{c:/texlive/2022/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}
] (./simple.aux) )<c:/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/public/amsfonts/cm/cm
r10.pfb>
Output written on simple.pdf (1 page, 12749 bytes).
SyncTeX written on simple.synctex.gz.

Transcript written on simple.log.
```

And for reference, the MWE is just:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
  Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Any ideas on why it might be hanging only in the VSCode compiler?

Comment: Try without "--shell-escape".

Comment: @vipa Unfortunately same behavior with or without --shell-escape

Comment: Seem that pdflatex can't find the file to compile specifies by VSCode through "%DOC%". Try without "%DOC%".

Comment: It does seem you're right that it isn't finding the file to compile. However, removing %DOC% doesn't seem to work. I also tried %DOC_W32%.tex, and %DOC_EXT_W32% as an option following [this](https://github.com/James-Yu/LaTeX-Workshop/wiki/Compile) but no luck so far.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately I discovered had defined

```
"latex-workshop.latex.external.build.command": "pdflatex"
```

Which low and behold states in the documentation:

> This is useful when compiling relies on a Makefile or a bespoke script. **When defined, it completely bypasses the recipes and root file detection mechanism.**

Overriding all the build commands that I had mentioned above. Clearing that and rerunning made everything work perfectly.